# How do I prove this equality between a recursive function and a non recursive one?

Tags: induction

I have the recursive function

$R(0) = 2$

$R(n) = \left(R(n-1)\right)^{2}$

And I found the non-recursive version of it

$P(n) = 2^{2^{n}}$

How do I prove they are the same through induction? I tried making $n = k + 1$ but got stuck on the R function

**Edit: Changed the 3s to 2s**

Comment: @RossMillikan I typed 3 instead of 2 and hadn't realized.

Comment: Just show that $P(0)=R(0)$ and $P(n)=\left(P(n-1)\right)^{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the base case,
$$R(0) = 2 = 2^1 = 2^{2^0} = P(0).$$
For the inductive case, assume that $R(n)=2^{2^n}$. We just need to prove that $R(n+1)=P(n+1)$.
\begin{align*}
R(n+1) &= (R(n+1-1))^2 \\
    &= (R(n))^2 \\
    &= (2^{2^n})^2\quad(\text{by the induction hypothesis}) \\
    &= 2^{2^n\cdot2} \\
    &= 2^{2^{n+1}} \\
    &= P(n+1).
\end{align*}